# Tesseract running local Makefile - pkgconfig: Permission denied

Tags: c++, makefile, permissions, tesseract, pkg-config

I have no problem to run Tesseract with Leptonica as administrator. But have small problem with running Tesseract wihout admin rights - locally.

Makefile looks like:

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS+=`pkg-config --cflags opencv`
LDFLAGS+=`pkg-config --libs opencv`
TSFLAGS+=`$(HOME)/local/lib/pkgconfig --libs $(HOME)/local/tesseract`

PROG=exp

.PHONY: all clean
$(PROG):
    $(CC) -o $(PROG) $(LDFLAGS) $(TSFLAGS)

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $<

all: $(PROG)

clean:
    rm -f $(PROG)
```

after make I see this error:

```
g++ -o exp `pkg-config --libs opencv` `/home/username/local/lib/pkgconfig --libs /home/username/local/tesseract`
/bin/sh: 1: /home/username/local/lib/pkgconfig: Permission denied
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:11: návod pro cíl „exp“ selhal
make: *** [exp] Chyba 1
```

I even tried to go further and in makefile I changed TSFLAGS ..../lib/pkgconfig/tesseract.pc. After this I saw this problem:

```
g++ -o exp `pkg-config --libs opencv` `/home/username/local/lib/pkgconfig/tesseract.pc --libs /home/username/local/tesseract`
/home/username/local/lib/pkgconfig/tesseract.pc: 4: /home/username/local/lib/pkgconfig/tesseract.pc: datarootdir: not found
/home/username/local/lib/pkgconfig/tesseract.pc: 9: /home/username/local/lib/pkgconfig/tesseract.pc: Name:: not found
/home/username/local/lib/pkgconfig/tesseract.pc: 10: /home/username/local/lib/pkgconfig/tesseract.pc: Description:: not found
/home/username/local/lib/pkgconfig/tesseract.pc: 11: /home/username/local/lib/pkgconfig/tesseract.pc: URL:: not found
/home/username/local/lib/pkgconfig/tesseract.pc: 12: /home/username/local/lib/pkgconfig/tesseract.pc: Version:: not found
/home/username/local/lib/pkgconfig/tesseract.pc: 13: /home/username/local/lib/pkgconfig/tesseract.pc: Requires.private:: not found
/home/username/local/lib/pkgconfig/tesseract.pc: 14: /home/username/local/lib/pkgconfig/tesseract.pc: Libs:: not found
/home/username/local/lib/pkgconfig/tesseract.pc: 15: /home/username/local/lib/pkgconfig/tesseract.pc: Libs.private:: not found
/home/username/local/lib/pkgconfig/tesseract.pc: 16: /home/username/local/lib/pkgconfig/tesseract.pc: Cflags:: not found
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:11: návod pro cíl „exp“ selhal
make: *** [exp] Chyba 1
```

tesseract.pc looks same on local and with admin rights:

```
prefix=/home/ondrej_mrhac/local
exec_prefix=${prefix}
bindir=${exec_prefix}/bin
datarootdir = ${prefix}/share
datadir=${datarootdir}
libdir=${exec_prefix}/lib
includedir=${prefix}/include/tesseract

Name: tesseract
Description: An OCR Engine that was developed at HP Labs between 1985 and 1995... and now at Google.
URL: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract
Version: 4.00.00dev
Requires.private: lept
Libs: -L${libdir} -ltesseract
Libs.private: -lpthread 
Cflags: -I${includedir}
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrongly?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe you ran `sudo ./configure` and it bound to some root directories.

Comment: Thank you for reaction, but unfortunately not. All configures were without sudo.....and all files (and folders hierarchy) in my home directory looks same as files in root directory...

Comment: By the way, when you say "administrator" what do you mean in linux? Is it running make with `sudo make` works but not without `sudo`?

Comment: I am testing my program on pc where I have all rights. But my program will run on machine, where will be limited rights - will be installed by user on linux server. I am running make without sudo

Comment: Ah, that is completely different. Likely it has nothing to do with rights, it's just that on the other machine it's missing some dependency. You haven't specified how it fails, however. Can you post the exact error message on the user's machine where it fails?

Comment: Solution:

line TSFLAGS+=`$(HOME)/local/lib/pkgconfig --libs $(HOME)/local/tesseract`

change to:

TSFLAGS+=-L$(HOME)/local/lib -ltesseract